# Use cases for Dynamic Permissions in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to understand what some of the uses cases are for dynamic permissions in Android. In other words, I am trying to understand why we have addPermission*() API methods and why just having static permissions is not sufficient. There doesn't seem to be much material out there explaining this, so I would appreciate some explanation.

Also, in order to understand what apps do with dynamic permissions, I downloaded some Android apps and started to reverse engineer them and look for the addPermission*() API methods in the source code. I've noticed that there are some apps that implement a wrapper class for PackageManager and I was wondering what the purpose is for doing this. Here is an example to the wrapper classes implemented by these apps, all they do is call the respective method of the PackageManager class:

```
public class PackageManagerWrapper
  extends PackageManager
{
  protected PackageManager mInner;

  public PackageManagerWrapper()
  {
    this.mInner = null;
  }

  public PackageManagerWrapper(Context paramContext)
  {
    this.mInner = paramContext.getPackageManager();
  }

  @Inject
  public PackageManagerWrapper(PackageManager paramPackageManager)
  {
    this.mInner = paramPackageManager;
  }

  public void addPackageToPreferred(String paramString)
  {
    this.mInner.addPackageToPreferred(paramString);
  }

  public boolean addPermission(PermissionInfo paramPermissionInfo)
  {
    return this.mInner.addPermission(paramPermissionInfo);
  }
...
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Apps can define custom permissions in order to protect it's code / data but still let other apps (with the right permission) to use it. While it's easy to think of use cases - like a suite of apps need to share a data/functionality only between them, those can be achieved by using a `<permission>` tag in manifest. However, this API used only for creating permissions not yet used by any other app:

> New permissions must be added before any .apks are installed that use those permissions. Permissions you add through this method are remembered across reboots of the device. If the given permission already exists, the info you supply here will be used to update it.

But still meant to be used by any app that had declared a [permission-tree](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-tree-element.html) in it's manifest.

So, since it's creating permissions at runtime and therefore cannot be applied to own Activities/Services, we are left only with broadcasts. The only advantage of this API over declaring those permissions in Manifest I can think of is that the user don't need to update the application. So if you are having a suit of apps, with one 'main' app (similar to Google Play), and you want to be able to broadcast to new apps in this suit securely even if the user had not updated your app, you can still get updates over the net and add needed permissions to communicate with the new apps.

For your second question - it's cannot be deducted from you example. There might be several reasons, such as acting as [Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern), or in order to add custom functionality.

Comment: Okay, but then why do you think it is a publicly available API?

Comment: For the second question, the wrapper class seems to be only calling the methods of the PackageManager class, without really adding any functionality.

Comment: Android OS is very modular, and many of what you might consider "OS" are apps (launcher, for an example). Naturaly, those apps can use only public Java methods. Some of those apps need to perform sensetive operations, so Android permission model allow only those "system apps" to use some of it's apis. So it's possible that this api cannot even be used by a non-system app, or it is, but useless without being able to install a package (which can be done only by a system app)

Comment: And for your second question - the bridge pattern allows you future flexibility, or handle better future changes in 3rd party libraries, even when not adding functinality. But this is only a guess, you'll need to ask library creators why they wrapped it :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. I definitely do see where you're coming from, but the fact that addPermission*() APIs not being tagged with "@SystemApi" or "@hide" makes me think they were publicly exposed to all apps on purpose.

Comment: You are right. It seems that any app can use it. I'll update my answer